# Unexpected behavior while using end to grow arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab

while building a video array from a directory of images I encounter unexpected behavior. Original code:

```
vid = [];
for i =startframe:endframe
    image = [directoryOfImages ,'\', images_names{1,i}];
    vid(:,:,:,end+1) = imread(image);
    waitbar((i-startframe) / (endframe-startframe));
end
```

Then I ran this code to check thing up:

```
a = []; size(a)
a(end+1) = 1; size(a)
```

The first size was `[0, 0]` and the second size was `[1, 1]`. The same expected behavior I got in this code:

```
b = []; size(b)
b(:,end+1) = 1; size(b)
```

The first size was `[0, 0]` and the second size was `[1, 1]`. But in this code, something weird happened:

```
c = []; size(c)
c(:,:,end+1) = 1; size(c)
```

while here the first size was `[0,0]` and the second one was `[1,1,2]`.
This was very unexpected. I printed `c` and I got this:

```
>>c
c(:,:,1) =

     0

c(:,:,2) =

     1
```

Finally, I ran this script:

```
c=[]; c(:,:,end)=1; size(c)
```

and I got `[1, 1]`.

can someone explain what is going on here? when I use `c=[]` do I get an empty array with the size of `[0,0,1]`? so how come `size(c)` doesn't mention it? and why when I use `c(:,:,end)=1;` its size is not `[1,1,1]`? and what about when I use `c(:,:,:,end)=1`?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but I do know that this is not memory allocation and that growing arrays this way in a loop is very bad in terms of computational time. Simply allocate your `vid` as `vid = zeros([size(image) endframe])`, or, if you don't know the size of the image beforehand and don't want to load the first one to get the size, let your loop run backwards (`for ii = endframe:-1:startframe`) and save in `vid` as `vid(:,:,:,ii)=...`, which automatically initiates the array to the proper size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just MATLAB choosing what to display.

In MATLAB, matrices are infinite dimensional. As a nice example, lets try your `b`:

```
b = []; 
b(:,end+1) = 1;
```

As you know, you can query the size of an specific dimension with `size`. E.g. `size(b,2)` returns `1`. But what does `size(b,12345)` return?, well, it returns `1` also, as matrices are infinite dimensional. In the 12345th dimension, the size of `b` is `1`.

However, what horrible would the display function be, if every time you type `size(b)` it outputs an infinite amount of dimensions! Thus when displaying, MATLAB defaults to displaying 2 dims OR N-dims, where N is the furthest dimension with data on it (non-singleton dimension).

Thus, what you are seeing with your `c` example is weird behaviour by the display function, not the `size` function. `size(c,3)` returns `1`. This is caused also by the `[]` only setting the size of the first two dimensions to zero, to avoid having a `MxPx0` variable when filling it up (`c(:,:,end)=img`, what happens with `end` ?), which is essentially an empty variable.

Comment: I try to understand why when I use c = [];c(:,:,end+1) = 1; size(c,3) I will get 2. my common sense is that I should get 1.

Comment: @AssafLivne what is `size(c,3)`? What is that size +1?

Comment: I think that he mean to compare with `b` in his question. Or, why the first to dimensions set to zero while all the rest set to 1?

Comment: @Adiel all of them are 1 by default, when you set to "empty", it doesnt set all of them to zero, just the first two

Comment: Your answer is very impressive but I think it requires more explanations 1+.

Comment: @rahnema1 I perhaps need to add some indeed. However none of this is "documented behaviour", it kind of just works like this

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I don't feel that I found an answer yet. I understand now that this is how Matlab decided to work, but I am trying to understand what is the purpose of it. I also work with python and c++, and both of them doesn't behave like this.

Comment: @AssafLivne I think its bydesign. I have no idea why they choose to do it this way, but its the way it works. C++ certainly doesn't behave like this, because the objects containing ND matrices are different.